# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php on live server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel.My website is working fine on localhost but as I hosted it on live server it redirects to Tokenmismatch Exception for all forms using post method.

```
I have tried following solutions:-

1.Change storage directory permission to 777.
2.Use command PHP artisan clear:cache.
3.check space in web.php file before <?php  tag.
4.Use **{{csrf_token()}}** in each form.

but still the problem is not solved.Please guide me.
```

Comment: try to set your session driver as `database` and see, and you should set token in a hidden field as `input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"` or alternatively `{{ csrf_field() }}` without making a hidden field your self..

Comment: I have tried {{ csrf_field() }} but it is also not working

Comment: @AkramWahid Thanks.can you please suggest any other alternative?